# How to print out functions from a loop of an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I be able to print out the objects that I gave the program in case 2

What I'm trying to implement is case 2 giving me all the info about the stuff I put into case 1

At first I tried to just use the setters and getters but for some reason I was having a **NullPointerException** when I used the do-while method.
So I decided to use the constructor but at the same time it gave me an error when trying to implement case 2. so any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        do{
            GameSale[] game;
            
            System.out.println("Hello! welcome to the menu!");
            System.out.println("Please Choose your option!");
            System.out.println(" 1-Enter a new game's Info \n 2-Check a game's Information \n 3- Check a game's sales \n 0-Exit");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            switch (choice){
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("How many games do you want to add? : ");
                    int size = input.nextInt();
                    game = new GameSale[size];
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {      
                    System.out.print("Enter Game "+(i+1) + "'s Name!: \n");
                    String tempname = input.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter the ID of the Game : \n");
                    int tempid = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.print("Enter the Game Type : \n");
                    String tempgametype=input.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter the development Company's Name : \n");
                    String tempgamecomp = input.next();  
                    System.out.print("Enter the Release Sale : \n");
                    double temprelsale = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter the total Sales : \n");
                    double temptotsale = input.nextDouble();
                    game[i]=new GameSale(temprelsale,temptotsale,tempid,tempname,tempgamecomp,tempgametype);
                        }break;
         case 2: 
                    for(int i = 0; i < game.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(game[i].toString());
                 }
                }while(choice!=0);
            }
        }
```

i got a class that has the setters and getters for some of the regular info

```
public class GameInfo {

    protected int ID;
    protected String GameName;
    protected String DevelopmentCompany;
    protected String GameType;
    
    public GameInfo(int ID, String GameName, String DevelopmentCompany, String GameType) {
        
        this.ID = ID;
        this.GameName = GameName;
        this.DevelopmentCompany = DevelopmentCompany;
        this.GameType = GameType;
    }
        
    public void SetID(int id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public int GetID() {
        System.out.println("The ID is " + ID);
        return ID;
    }

    public void SetName(String Name) {
        this.GameName = Name;
        
    }

    public String GetName() {
        System.out.println("The Name of the Game Is " + GameName);
        return GameName;

    }

    public void SetCompanyName(String CompanyName) {
        this.DevelopmentCompany = CompanyName;
        
    }

    public String GetCompanyName() {
        System.out.println("The Name Of the Development company Is " + DevelopmentCompany);
        return DevelopmentCompany;
    }
    public void SetGameType(String GameType){
        this.GameType=GameType;
        
    }
    public String GetGameType(){
        System.out.println("The Game Type is : "+GameType);
        return GameType;
    }
}
```

and a super class with the sales and a constructor for the sales

```
public class GameSale extends GameInfo {
    protected double ReleaseSales;
    protected double TotalSales;

    public GameSale(double ReleaseSales, double TotalSales, int ID, String GameName, String DevelopmentCompany, String GameType) {
        super(ID, GameName, DevelopmentCompany, GameType);
        this.ReleaseSales = ReleaseSales;
        this.TotalSales = TotalSales;
    }

    public void SetReleaseSales(double RelSale){
        this.ReleaseSales=RelSale;
        
    }
     public void SetTotalSales(double totSales){
        this.TotalSales=totSales;
            }
     
     public double GetReleaseSales(){
         System.out.println("The Release Sales Are "+ReleaseSales );
         return ReleaseSales;
     }
     public double GetTotalSales(){
         System.out.println("The Total Sales Are "+TotalSales);
         return TotalSales;

     }
}
```

**Answered by Alex (thanks a lot dude)**
here's a temporary fix just for debugging so far by initializing the array dimensions outside the do-while loop

**main**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GameProject {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
    int choice;
    GameSale[] games = new GameSale[1];

    do {
      System.out.println("Hello! welcome to the menu!");
      System.out.println("Please Choose your option!");
      System.out.println(" 1-Enter a new game's Info \n 2-Check a game's Information \n 3- Check a game's sales \n 0-Exit");
      choice = input.nextInt();
      switch (choice) {
      case 0:
        break;
      case 1:

        for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
          System.out.print("Enter Game " + (i + 1) + "'s Name!: \n");
          String tempname = input.next();
          System.out.print("Enter the ID of the Game : \n");
          int tempid = input.nextInt();
          System.out.print("Enter the Game Type : \n");
          String tempgametype = input.next();
          System.out.print("Enter the development Company's Name : \n");
          String tempgamecomp = input.next();
          System.out.print("Enter the Release Sale : \n");
          double temprelsale = input.nextDouble();
          System.out.print("Enter the total Sales : \n");
          double temptotsale = input.nextDouble();
          games[i] = new GameSale(temprelsale, temptotsale, tempid, tempname, tempgamecomp, tempgametype);
        }
        break;
      case 2:
        for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(games[i].toString());
        }

      }
    } while ( choice != 0 );
  }
}
```

**game info**

```
public class GameInfo {

    protected int ID;
    protected String GameName;
    protected String DevelopmentCompany;
    protected String GameType;
    
    public GameInfo(int ID, String GameName, String DevelopmentCompany, String GameType) {
        
        this.ID = ID;
        this.GameName = GameName;
        this.DevelopmentCompany = DevelopmentCompany;
        this.GameType = GameType;
    }
        
    public void SetID(int id) {
        this.ID = id;
    }

    public int GetID() {
        System.out.println("The ID is " + ID);
        return ID;
    }

    public void SetName(String Name) {
        this.GameName = Name;
        
    }

    public String GetName() {
        System.out.println("The Name of the Game Is " + GameName);
        return GameName;

    }

    public void SetCompanyName(String CompanyName) {
        this.DevelopmentCompany = CompanyName;
        
    }

    public String GetCompanyName() {
        System.out.println("The Name Of the Development company Is " + DevelopmentCompany);
        return DevelopmentCompany;
    }
    public void SetGameType(String GameType){
        this.GameType=GameType;
        
    }
    public String GetGameType(){
        System.out.println("The Game Type is : "+GameType);
        return GameType;
    }
}
```

**game sale**

```
public class GameSale extends GameInfo {
    protected double ReleaseSales;
    protected double TotalSales;

    public GameSale(double ReleaseSales, double TotalSales, int ID, String GameName, String DevelopmentCompany, String GameType) {
        super(ID, GameName, DevelopmentCompany, GameType);
        this.ReleaseSales = ReleaseSales;
        this.TotalSales = TotalSales;
    }

    public void SetReleaseSales(double RelSale){
        this.ReleaseSales=RelSale;
        
    }
     public void SetTotalSales(double totSales){
        this.TotalSales=totSales;
            }
     
     public double GetReleaseSales(){
         System.out.println("The Release Sales Are "+ReleaseSales );
         return ReleaseSales;
     }
     public double GetTotalSales(){
         System.out.println("The Total Sales Are "+TotalSales);
         return TotalSales;

     }

 
     public String toString(){
    return this.ID + " " + this.GameName + " " + this.DevelopmentCompany + " " + this.GameType;
}}
```

Comment: GetName add parantheses ()

Comment: @AlexRudenko where in GameSale do you see this method?

Comment: @Alex, it was edited, never mind

Comment: just switched the setters and getters types

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase.

Comment: Where do you give a value to i in your first code in case 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to print a game's info at a given index in case 2:

```
if (game == null) { // Break if no game exists
    System.out.println("There is no games to show!");
    break;
}
System.out.print("Enter game index to show information: ");
int index = input.nextInt();
// Break if index is not in bounds
if (index < 0 || index > game.length) {
    System.out.println("Incorrect index");
    break;
}

System.out.println("Info of game: " + game[index].toString());
```

This code should ask for index as input and prints the info of the game and it will print 'There is no games to show!' if there was no any game added yet

Note you must add the toString() method in your GameSale class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + this.ID + " Name: " + this.GameName + " Development Company: " + 
      this.DevelopmentCompany + " Game Type: " + this.GameType + " Release Sales: " + ReleaseSales + " Total Sales: " + TotalSales;
}
```

also move the decleration of the game variable out of the scope of the do-while loop (above it) it will look like

```
GameSale[] game = null; 
do { ...
```

Also if you want case 2 to show all games info you can replace the index part with a loop that iterates the whole 'game' array and prints every element's toString.

Comment: got a java.lang.NullPointerException error at the start of the for loop in case 1 please check the updated code @Daniel

Comment: Could you please explain to me more, where is the NullPointerException exactly?

Comment: Right on the for-loop  ``` case 1:

        for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) ```

Comment: I tried running the code, it worked fine for me no exception at all, are you sure the one you are running is updated here?

Comment: i changed the updated one to the ones you listed above and it gave me the exception on the for-loop

Comment: it's giving me a warning on the for-loop saying "dereferencing possible on null pointer"

Comment: If the NullPointerException is on for-loop line then games variable must be null!, haven't you initialized it before the for-loop? `  int size = input.nextInt();
                    game = new GameSale[size];`

Comment: oh. just fixed it thanks to that. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

#### toString()

In your class you should implement a `toString()` method.
This basically returns all the property values of your object as a String

```
public String toString(){
return this.ID + " " + this.GameName + " " + this.DevelopmentCompany + " " + this.GameType;
}
```

Then call it on your object in case2

```
game[i].toString()
```

#### Display

To list all games you have to iterate over your gamesArray and print out the informations with your toString() method;

```
for(int i = 0; i < games.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(game[i].toString());
}
```

### Scope

Create the games array outside of you case1 scope.

```
GameSale[] game = new GameSale[SomeFixedSize];
```

Comment: problem is that the array is inside case 1 so it's giving me an error on game[i]

Comment: @FadyMohamedElganzoury define it one scope higher. For instance define it outside of your case1: and then just initialise it in case1 then it should also be available in case2

Comment: so put it at the start of the do{ ? cuz  still having the same error

Comment: no put it outside of the case two. Currently you are initialising and declaring it inside.
 `GameSale[] game = new GameSale[size];` here the declaring part, put the declaring part outside of your case2 and then just initialize it in case2 `game[i]=new GameSale(temprelsale,temptotsale,tempid,tempname,tempgamecomp,tempgametype);`

Comment: Can you share the full code in the class where case1 and case2 is or is it on github?

Comment: @FadyMohamedElganzoury have you tried it out?

Comment: Just added the full code tho i didn't quiet get what you meant by declaring it outside of case2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227057/discussion-between-fady-mohamed-elganzoury-and-alex).